# Problems with RVM installing Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby using RVM on a Macbook Pro running Mavericks. I'm a little over my head, but whenever I type in `rvm install 2.1` it fails and gives me the following error:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.1.1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/ianvshuff/.rvm/log/1396019921_ruby-2.1.1/update_system.log
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Xcode is installed and everything. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If "RVM INSTALL 2.1" is not really what you type in, please use the *real* text you enter. *nix is case-sensitive and `RVM INSTALL` would fail with a "command not found" type of error. If you were trying to call-out your text to make it more visible, then please read the [Stack Overflow editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It will make your life easier, and will encourage others to read and answer your questions.

Comment: Absolutely, I will make sure to note that and I'll post differently from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like RVM is trying to install some requirements by using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which is not installed or configured correctly. You can install Homebrew, or type `rvm requirements` and try to resolve them manually.